# exit command behaves differently in Linux and HP-UX

Tags: linux, ksh, exit

I am working in HP-UX (B.11.23) to LINUX (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5  - Santiago) migration project. There were several occurrences where HP-UX commands were not working properly in Linux. But, in following situation - I am facing some difficulties to find out an alternate solution.

Following piece of code is just an example from a script, but requesting you to understand the final outcome of the code.

```
## Assigning a text value in retval (bad path scenario)_
retval="ERROR"
if [ $retval -eq 7 ]
then
     echo "I am in " $retval
fi
exit $retval
```

Executing this code in LINUX...

```
LINUX $> ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
LINUX $> ksh -x test12.ksh
+ retval=ERROR
+ [ ERROR -eq 7 ]
+ exit ERROR
tpl06429dat05::edwprod::/home/edwprod >echo $?
0
# look here return code of above executed script is 0_
```

Now, have executed same code in HP_UX

```
UNIX $> uname -a
HP-UX ipeip06 B.11.23 U ia64 ******** unlimited-user license
UNIX $> strings /bin/ksh | grep Version | tail -2
@(#)Version 11/16/88
UNIX $> ksh -x test12.ksh
+ retval=ERROR
+ [ ERROR -eq 7 ]
test12.ksh[3]: ERROR: bad number
+ exit ERROR
test12.ksh[8]: ERROR: bad number
UNIX $> echo $?
1
# Look here, return code of above executed code is 1
```

In Linux, "exit" command is not executed at all as I have passes wrong parameter (string), but in HP-UX there is no problem - "exit" command with wrong parameter has been executed and tells us that it's a wrong command (echo $?) in that script. And this return code is very important as based on this return code ($?), we decide whether a script has been executed successfully (0) or not.

I understand, if we tweak the code, then problem can be resolved. But that's bit difficult here as I am dealing with almost 15K or more such scripts which are written in HP_UX.
Is there any possibility to change something at OS level (changing packages/parameters).. What kind of system level changes needed?

On a different note, ksh versions are different and behaves differently. So, it's better if you avoid this answer.

Comment: What versions of `ksh` are you using on both machines?

Comment: Can't you fornat your code correctly, with real linebreaks? `-eq` works for numbers only, not for strings.

Comment: I'd recommend you change the scripts anyway, if they're actually passing unquoted variables to `test`.

Comment: What horrible code. The “UNIX” output isn't any more correct than the “LINUX” output. Linux does execute the `exit` command, it just interprets the bad argument differently — the solution is of course not to pass a bad argument.

Comment: “UNIX” is meaningless. Unix is a family of operating systems, of which Linux is a subfamily. What variant of Unix is the one that isn't Linux? What version of ksh are you running on both?

Comment: Please provide specific details on the Linux and UNIX you are using.  You may be making an over-generalization due to specific implementation of the utility programs by the vendor involved.  Also, can I ask why you are exiting with an error code that is a text string and not a simple unsigned small integer?

Comment: I've shown why you're getting different results, but if you want some more practical help on what to change, you'll have to explain your script:  Both of your `if` branches have exactly the same content (`echo "I am in " $retval`) and you're comparing a constant error message with a number.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have revised the question. Please check and let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: `exit` is implemented by the shell, not the OS, so it probably *is* down to the
individual versions of `ksh` rather than whether it's HP-UX or linux.

Comment: "This return code is very important" - how?  On any one machine (OS+shell), it will always give the same result, so there's no point checking it.  Please could you show one of these 15K scripts, to demonstrate what other exit status they might give?

Comment: @JigglyNaga We have scheduled these scripts in "Control M" tool which determines SUCCESS/FAILURE of a job based on exit status. These scripts mainly call OWB/ODI maps or PROCEDURE to do a job. During sudden restart of database, it does not get proper return code and old shell scripts are not intelligent enough to capture other than numeric value. Rather than changing all shell scripts manually, I wanted to do something from system level. Hope, you have got my problem.

Comment: "Hope, you have got my problem."  Not really, no.  You still haven't shown a script that could give a different result (ie. doesn't always reach the broken `exit` statement).  But if installing a different (k)sh fixes your problem, is my answer acceptable?

Comment: AFAICS you're trying to patch broken scripts by using a broken shell, which will just break again in the future. At some point someone will have to fix it. Who is going to do that? When? Why not now?

Answer (score 4):

Your script ends

```
exit $retval
```

And you set `retval` to a string (whose first word is "ERROR:").

According to the [specification for the `exit` builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/exit.html),

> The exit utility shall cause the shell to exit with the exit status specified by the unsigned decimal integer n. If n is specified, but its value is not between 0 and 255 inclusively, the exit status is undefined.

"undefined" means that it's OK, and sometimes even expected, for different implementations to give different results.

Looking at your `ksh` versions, the one on HP-UX (11/16/88) gives exit status 1, while the one on your Linux installation (93u+) gives exit status 0.  If you want the Linux system to behave more like the HP-UX one, you'll have to install a different ksh that behaves the old way, such as [mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) or [pdksh](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/).

Comment: Thanks.. I think that is only option. Have tried with "bash" - it's working fine.